# How do I add a string of numbers in python

Tags: python

For instance if I have the string entered 345. I want them to be added 3 + 4 + 5. I've seen this here before just can't seem to find it again. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
s = raw_input()
print sum(int(c) for c in s.strip())
```

Answer (score 12):

Maybe it's my Scheme getting to me, but I'd use `map` here. `map(int, s)` says "take this sequence but with all its elements as integers". That is, it's the same as `[int(x) for x in s]`, but faster to read/type.

```
>>> x = "345"
>>> sum(map(int, x))
12
```

Comment: +1. `map` is more pythonic than a generator expression in this case.

Comment: What is map for? and what does it do?

Answer (score 6):

```
data = "345"
print sum([int(x) for x in data])
```

Comment: +1, but works without square brackets as well: `sum(int(x) for x in data)`

Answer (score 1):

```
In [4]: text='345'

In [5]: sum(int(char) for char in text)
Out[5]: 12
```

or if you want the string `3+4+5`:

```
In [8]: '+'.join(char for char in text)
Out[8]: '3+4+5'
```

Comment: What Python shell do you use?

Answer (score -1):

What unutbu said plus, if the number is an int, not a string:

```
num = 345    
sum([int(x) for x in str(num)])
```